# Checking for new files in Netsuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

Is there a way to check a folder for new files or to check the age of a file?

For example, if I have a few files in a folder, is it possible for me to find out which one is the newest using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do a document search and sort the results by Date Created in descending order.

Comment: Hmm...that's what I was thinking as well. Wasn't sure if it was possible. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can also do a saved search using SuiteScript:

```
x = nlapiSearchRecord('file', null, ['folder', 'anyof', YOUR_FOLDER_ID], [new nlobjSearchColumn('created').setSort(true)]);
```

You will get the recently created file first in the search result.

Alternatively, you can create the Document search from UI as suggested by @RUSTY and then load the same search using `nlapiLoadSearch()` API

Comment: Thank you @prasun, I'll try that.